# sc parallelize function not working with unity catalog

Tags: json, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We have this code worjking fine with databricks runtime 10

```
request_url = https://.com/?fct=Get
response_task = requests.get(url=request_url, headers=headers)
db1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([response_task.text])`
df2 = spark.read.json(db1)
```

we have this error using runtime 13.3 due to limitation is there another way to serialize [response_task.text] with large volumes:

```
An error occurred while calling o398.createRDDFromTrustedPath. Trace: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createRDDFromTrustedPath(java.lang.String,int) is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession at py4j.security.WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.checkCall(WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.java:473) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:305) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195) at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

```
response_task = requests.get(url=request_url_gettasks, headers=headers)

response_text = response_task.text

db1 = spark.read.json([response_text])
```

com.databricks.rpc.UnexpectedHttpException: Got invalid response: 502

This code seems to work (to be tested with volumes)

```
response_task = requests.get(url=request_url_gettasks, headers=headers)
response_text = response_task.text
task_data = json.loads(response_text)["results"]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("PROJECT_ID", IntegerType()),
    StructField("PROJECT_NAME", StringType()),
    StructField("PROJECT_NUMBER", StringType()),
    StructField("PROJECT_TYPE_NAME", StringType()),
    ....)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(task_data, schema)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work (to be tested with volumes)

```
response_task = requests.get(url=request_url_gettasks, headers=headers)
response_text = response_task.text
task_data = json.loads(response_text)["results"]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("PROJECT_ID", IntegerType()),
    StructField("PROJECT_NAME", StringType()),
    StructField("PROJECT_NUMBER", StringType()),
    StructField("PROJECT_TYPE_NAME", StringType())
    )
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(task_data, schema)
```